# why some fields are not saved in a OneToOneField model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

In my models.py, I'm extending the User model, thanks to a OneToOneField:

```
class MyUser(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    # Extra fields:
    favourite_colour = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Then, in views.py, I'm trying to save from a form:

```
 def register(request):
     if request.POST:
         form = UserForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid(): 
             username = form.cleaned_data['username']
             password = form.cleaned_data['password']
             favourite_colour = form.cleaned_data['favourite_colour']
             new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
             new_user.save()
             new_myuser = MyUser(user=new_user)
             new_myuser.favourite_colour = favourite_colour
             # IF I COMMENT OUT THE LINE BELOW, the fields of User are correctly saved
             new_myuser.save()

             # TESTING WHETHER IT'S SAVED :
             print("{} was saved in User, with username = {}".format(new_user, new_user.username))

             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            # display the page with the errors
            return render(request, 'registration/registration_form.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        # display the blank form:
        form = UserForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/registration_form.html', {'form': form})
```

If I test it with, for example, a simple form I get:
`person1 was saved in User, with username = person1`.

But if I check in my database (db.sqlite3), the object created has no username or password, only `id`, `is_superuser`, `is_staff`, `is_active`, `date_joined` are defined.

It's as if my fields `password` and `username` are erased after.

As noted in comment inside the code, if I comment out  `MyUser.save()` (the model `MyUser` which is linked to `User` by a OneToOneField), the fields inside `User` are correctly filled (but the linked model `MyUser` stays empty obviously)

Comment: You should also check if `form.cleaned_data['username']` and `form.cleaned_data['password']` are there, then check right after `new_user.save()` to see if `new_user` has `username` `password` setup correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused two concepts here: inheritance and relationships. You've declared MyUser as inheriting from User; that means it automatically gains all the fields from User. But you have *also* defined a relationship to the User class; the instance of User in that relationship is not the same as the one you are inheriting from.

You shouldn't do this. If you want to create a relationship, do that: remove the inheritance, creating the instances separately as your code already does, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Roseman is correct. If you want to extend your User model, you should create a `UserProfile` model that has a one-to-one relationship. Here is a common pattern:

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, relate_name='userprofile')
    favourite_colour = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def get_or_create_profile(user):
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return profile

User.userprofile = property(get_or_create_profile)
```

**views.py**

```
 def register(request):
     if request.POST:
         form = UserForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid(): 
             username = form.cleaned_data['username']
             password = form.cleaned_data['password']
             favourite_colour = form.cleaned_data['favourite_colour']
             user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)

             userprofile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
             if created:
                 userprofile.favourite_colour = favourite_colour
                 userprofile.save()
             else:
                 print '... User/UserProfile already exists! Handle that here...'

             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            # display the page with the errors
            return render(request, 'registration/registration_form.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        # display the blank form:
        form = UserForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/registration_form.html', {'form': form})
```